# How to only save certain values in edit razor page

Tags: c#, razor

I currently have an edit page where I have an invoice. It is a picture saved as a binary value.

When I want to edit an invoice, I want the picture to stay the same but when I press save, it gets rid of the image and updates the row to null.

Would it possibly have something to do with my Edit Method?

Here is part of my razor page:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    if (Model.PictureOfInvoice != null)
    {
        var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.PictureOfInvoice);
        var imgsrc = string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", base64);
        <img src="@imgsrc" style="max-width:500px;max-height:500px" align="right" />
    }
}

<h2>Details of Invoice</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Invoice</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.InvoiceId)
```

Is there any way for this not to be updated?

**EDIT**

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    Invoice invoice = db.Invoices.Find(id);
    if (invoice == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    ViewBag.ChurchId = new SelectList(db.Churches, "ChurchId", "Name", invoice.ChurchId);
    return View(invoice);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "InvoiceId,Company,Description,Amount,ChurchId")] Invoice invoice)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(invoice).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.ChurchId = new SelectList(db.Churches, "ChurchId", "Name", invoice.ChurchId);
    return View(invoice);
}
```

My Model:

```
public class Invoice
{
    [Key]
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }

    public string Company { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public byte[] PictureOfInvoice { get; set; }

    public string ImageFileName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Church")]
    public int ChurchId { get; set; }

    public virtual Church Church { get; set; }

    public virtual Administration Admins { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You didn't post how you are saving to/retrieving from the database

Comment: @mjwills my bad, just updated the question

Comment: In the `Edit` method you need to get the existing entry out of the database and alter it. Otherwise **any** property that isn't passed as part of the request will be lost (including the image).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "InvoiceId,Company,Description,Amount,ChurchId")] Invoice invoice)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Invoice oldInvoice = db.Invoices.Find(id);
        oldInvoice.Amount = invoice.Amount;
        // repeated for all of the properties (but not the image)

        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ViewBag.ChurchId = new SelectList(db.Churches, "ChurchId", "Name", invoice.ChurchId);
    return View(invoice);
}
```

The key is to use `db.Invoices.Find` to get the existing item out of the database. That way existing properties (like the image) won't be lost.